# Connection failed from Visual Studio 2022 (MAUI, Xamarin) to macOS

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin

I updated macos to version 13 Ventura. I'm developing apps using Xamarin/MAUI on Visual Studio on Windows. Access to macOS over the network is no longer possible. Error message: Unable to connect to SSH using the SSH keys. I have enabled remote access to macOS.

Comment: Unfortunately that's the reality at this moment. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/how-to-report-a-problem-with-visual-studio?view=vs-2022 Report it to Microsoft and wait for an update.

Comment: I confirm that it also does not work here. On a setup that worked, prior to software updates on Mac.

Answer (score 1):

Please ne noted that `macOS 13 (Ventura)` ships with [OpenSSH_9.0p1](https://www.openssh.com/txt/release-9.0).

You can try to **edit** `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` and save it.

```
HostkeyAlgorithms +ssh-rsa
PubkeyAcceptedAlgorithms +ssh-rsa
```

And then **restart** the Mac and Visual Studio.

Answer (score 0):

This was an bug on Visual Studio 17.3.4 (see https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/macOS-Ventura-130-Beta---Impossible-to/10163760?q=%5BFixed+In%3A+Visual+Studio+2022+version+17.4%5D) that is fixed on 17.4.0, so update to Visual Studio 17.4.0 and the error is gone.